# HTTP Response. How can you tell if the response has gone through a proxy?

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, proxy

I am wanting to log information about the HTTP requests I send through my C# ASP.NET Web Application.

I want to log the proxy used for the request.

The requests use the default proxy specified by the web.config, but the default proxy has a bypass list and when the request is to one of the domains specified by the bypass list, it will not use the proxy.

I'm guessing that there must be information in the HTTP request about the proxy that its going to use or maybe in the response in the proxy it used.

Answer (score 0):

You can capture this via the [`Via`](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) (pun intended) response header:

> Informs the client of proxies through which the response was sent.

```
Via: 1.0 fred, 1.1 example.com (Apache/1.1)
```

Comment: Awesome, so are proxies separated by comma?

So fred was the proxy and example.com was the server?

Comment: Yes. Thats how it's works. I suggest you diagnose afew real requests and see how they work

Comment: Yes. Thats how it's works. I suggest you diagnose afew real requests and see how they work